# TailWindCSS input field change in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a question

I have an input field using Tailwindcss for styling, as demonstrated in
https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-cra-forked-v0cx3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I am having trouble with removing background in input and in autofill. nothing seems to work.

Can someone help, please?
Thanks

Comment: In the example you provided in codesandbox, there is no checkbox...?

Comment: to help, perhaps you might like to also describe specifically what you have tried doing and why it doesn't seem to work for you...

Comment: Danoz. i am not sure why checkbox shows up in the question. .. I resolved checkbox issue just before I posted this question.

so here is what is I am dealing with. I cannot seem to remove a whitebackground of autofill in input field. It shows up white. I need to remove the background. Thank you!

Comment: That helps clear it up Aurinko Bay... I've posted a possible answer below, let me know there if that is what you are looking for...

Answer (score 15):

I was having problems with autofill in Chrome/Webkit browsers. Thanks to [this CSS tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/change-autocomplete-styles-webkit-browsers/), I was able to fix it by adding this to my `globals.css`:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

/* Change Autocomplete styles in Chrome*/
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  border: 1px solid #253341;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #253341 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #253341 inset;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
  color: white;
}
```

As of Tailwind 3, you can also use the `autofill` pseudo-class, but I didn't find this helpful:

```html
<input class="autofill:!bg-yellow-200 ..." />
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#autofill

Here I'm combining it with the "Important Modifier": https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important-modifier

Answer (score 2):

I made it work with Autoprefixer as described in [Tailwind official docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/browser-support#vendor-prefixes).

The idea is to install `autoprefixer` and add it to Tailwind plugins.
You can do it like so:

```
npm install -D autoprefixer
# or
yarn add -D autoprefixer
```

Add to `tailwind.config.js` or your PostCSS config:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
  ]
}
```

Then, it will add rules like `-webkit-autofill` when you write `autofill:something` in Tailwind.

To change the autofill background color, you actually need to set the `box-shadow` like so:

```
autofill:shadow-[inset_0_0_0px_1000px_rgb(255,255,0)]
```

That will set an inset box shadow with yellow color on your input field when autofilled.

Answer (score 0):

example code:

```js
const normalCls = clsx(
  'autofill:border-green-500 autofill:shadow-[inset_0_0_0px_1000px_rgba(34,197,94,0.1)]',
  'autofill:transition-[background-color] autofill:duration-[5000s] autofill:delay-0 autofill:ease-in-out'
);
```

same as:

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  @apply border border-green-500 shadow-[inset_0_0_0px_1000px_rgba(34,197,94,0.1)];
  @apply transition-[background-color] duration-[5000s] delay-0 ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend boxShadow in your tailwind.config.js:

```
theme: {
    extend: {
        boxShadow: {
            'innerColor': '0 0 0px 1000px #343159 inset',
        },
    },
},
```

Then, you can use it by calling the class `autofill:shadow-innerColor` in tailwind.

Note: The above result was adapted from [Jp Lew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011766/jp-lew) answer.