# How to override "-internal-autofill-selected" style with tailwindcss?

Tags: css, user-interface, browser, tailwind-css, autofill

I have a form with two fields, when the email field gets auto-filled, Chrome mysteriously adds this styling:

```
input:-internal-autofill-selected {
    appearance: menulist-button;
    background-image: none !important;
    background-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(232, 240, 254), rgba(70, 90, 126, 0.4)) !important;
    color: fieldtext !important;
}
```

How to disable it by using tailwindcss?

Desired outcome would be that input keeps background-color of inherit.

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64148246/tailwindcss-input-field-change-in-react

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
input[type="password"], input[type="email"] {
background-image: url('url') !important;
background-color: -internal-light-dark(rgba(232, 240, 254, rgba(70, 90, 
126, 0)0.4)) !important;
color: red !important;
}
```